# How to move spheres in 3d without collision

Tags: algorithms

Is there an algorithm that gets as an input 2 arrays (arr_origin, arr_dest) that represent spheres with a set radius (R) in a 3d space, (x,y,z) points. And finds a route for the spheres from origin to dest without collisions, in the fastest way given each sphere can move at a speed from 0 to V?

Comment: Is the ratio (R) for all spheres the same?

Comment: @MarceloFornet Yes.

Comment: Are you interested in the fastest way or approximations. For example if you don't care to be to fast you can design an algorithm that move all sphere from any distribution A, to some Canonical distribution C, then if you want to move from A to B you just do A -> C -> B (Notice that C -> B is the same than B -> C but backwards).

Comment: Also, it worth to think the simpler instance of this problem in 2D, it looks like they have similar complexity and maybe solution to 2D can be generalized to 3D.

Comment: Are the spheres constrained to travel in a straight line or not ? At constant speed or not ? Should all spheres arrive simultaneously ?

Comment: A priori, it seems that an exact solution is extremely arduous.

Answer (score 0):

Here's how I would do it:
Create an oriented bounding box around the path of each sphere, with dimensions equal to the sphere's diameter. Now perform collision detection on all of those bounding boxes. For the ones which do not collide, their correlating sphere's can travel at max velocity.
For the bounding boxes that DO collide, do they collide at a point equidistant to the spheres' starting points (+/-  radii)? If not then they are free to move at max velocity. 
If they DO collide at an equidistant point(+/- radii), then you must slow one sphere down so that it will not collide.

Hope this helps.
Good luck!

Comment: I am assuming in your solution you are moving each sphere through the line that connects origin with destiny. Here goes an edge case ... What if there is an sphere that doesn't need to be moved but another needs to go through it, how do you decide in such cases?

Comment: Great question and edge case. My assumption.. probably a bad one...was that the spheres could only move on a straight line. If that is true then there would be no solution for your edge case. If it is not true, then the problem becomes much harder. Consider the edge case also that 2 spheres have the same end point, they could not both occupy the point regardless of their movement. Thanks for pointing this out Marcelo!

Comment: @GabrielRohweder We can assume that the input won't allow this. All the end positions are w/o collisions.

Comment: What is the point using bounding boxes around the spheres ? Direct sphere collision detection is easier !

Comment: I think you miss the point, the alternative is not sphere to sphere collision, it would be capsule-capsule collision, as the bounding box is bounding the PATH of the sphere not the sphere itself.

Answer (score 0):

In the case of two spheres

- if the two straight-line trajectories do not interfere (in space-time), this is the optimal solution and the time taken is the length of the longest trajectory over the maximum speed;
- if they do interfere, there are several options:

  - let the two spheres travel in a straight line, and let the one with the shortest distance wait when it meets the other; more precisely, it can come in contact with it and remain so until the path is freed; note that if that would imply a backward move, the second sphere should anticipate and stop when it hits the envelope of the trajectory of the first (a cylindre);
  - let the sphere with the longest distance travel in a straight line and let the other deviate to avoid it, both at maximum speed; the modified trajectory will be made of two straight portions and some complex curve in between (to be determined by variation calculus ?);
  - keep both spheres at maximum speed and slow down both when they come in contact; there should be optimal relations between the speeds over time and the total time spent;
  - deviate both spheres optimally (?);
  - combine stalling and deviation in the best way.

This just gives you a taste of the problem complexity.